# python django show only once occurance of field from object/model

Tags: python, django

I have a model in python which has:

```
user: bob dept: sales
user: bill dept: sales
user fred dept: marketing
```

Want I want to be able to do is just get the words sales and marketing into a list once. Bascially a list of unique depts that I can process later.

The `pdUser` class is below:

```
class pdUser(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Dept = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Mobile = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    PagerDutyID = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    PagerDutyPolicyID = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    PagerDutyPolicy = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: Could you post some code, e.g. the model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into `values_list` and `distinct`:

```
depts = pdUser.objects.values_list('Dept', flat=True).distinct()
```